# Problem with Byte Flood Cryptography (C library)

Tags: c, sockets, cryptography, stream

I have a little problem with a C library: Byte Flood Cryptography. ( http://bfcrypt.sourceforge.net ).

I would create a program which use both linux sockets and Byte Flood Cryptography (the Byte Flood Cryptography functions are near from those provided from stdio.h, and this, I have understand).

I don't know how to *'bind'* the two stream. I would encrypt data directly to the network.
How can I do?? (I don't want to use temporary array or files)

Comment: It may just be that the library's author is a non-native english speaker (hence a poor choice of words), but I'd be more than a little skeptical of any crypto that describes itself as "mathematically invulnerable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use that library.  Use only ciphers and protocols that were designed *and reviewed* by professional cryptographers, not crackpots who talk about "non-mathematical" approaches to cipher design.

I'd reach for [GnuTLS](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/) (for C programs) or [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) (if C++ is okay), myself.  OpenSSL is popular but has a weird license and should not be used for new code.

Comment: Ok... Thanks Zack. I think I will use GnuTLS (it's a C program, and thank to torak and Zack, I think Byte Flood Cryptography -um- uncertified...)